# Trying to inline a HyperLinkButton in a TextBlock

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, inlines

I'm adding Inlines to a TextBlock.  The Run() inlines work.  Of course the Hyperlink() is deprecated in Windows 8 (using Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents) for some reason, so I'm trying to encapsulate a HyperlinkButton in an InlineUIContainer using C#.  I know the concept is sound, but my code is failing.

if I comment out the line "using Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents;" then I get the two surrounding inlines to show up in my ListView (which uses the method below.)  If this line is uncommented, the Inlines.Add for 'link' is throwing.  What am I doing wrong?

> ```
>     public TextBlock enrichPostText(anFullPost post)
>     {
>         TextBlock text_block = new TextBlock();
>         text_block.Inlines.Clear();
> ```

```
        var holdText = new Run();
        holdText.Text = "Test start >> ";
        text_block.Inlines.Add(holdText);

        HyperlinkButton linkButton = new HyperlinkButton();
        linkButton.NavigateUri = new Uri("http://www.cones.net");
        linkButton.Content = "click me";
        linkButton.Name = "_blank";

        InlineUIContainer link = new InlineUIContainer();
        link.Child = linkButton;

        text_block.Inlines.Add(link);

        var holdText2 = new Run();
        holdText2.Text = " << end test.";
        text_block.Inlines.Add(holdText2);

        return (text_block);
    }
```

Comment: Note: if I comment out the line: text_block.Inlines.Add(link); then the other Inlines work and I can see the ListViewItems.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: WinRT information: E_NETWORK_ERROR

Answer (score 2):

Just found this on MSDN which might be helpful. Apparently TextBlock content model does not support InlineUIContainers so it will throw an exception.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/96585db1-8ed4-4a12-8d63-b427dc0d543d/

Answer (score 0):

I just tried changing my `RichTextBlock` to a `TextBlock`, and I'm also seeing an `ArgumentException` get thrown when I try to add the `InlineUIContainer`. The only solution I know is to use `RichTextBlock` instead; so far it's been suiting my needs.